# how to automatically generate a unique c++ class based on a file

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-development

let me preface this question by saying I have no idea if I'm asking the right question. I'm pretty new to c++ and I haven't gotten all of its nuances down yet, but I have coded in other OOP languages for nearly 7 years.

I originally asked:
Is there a way to take a text file and automatically generate c++ code? If yes, how do I do that? What are some resources that explain the process?

but to clarify, what I really want is:
Is there some way to take a text file, or other file type (like json) and use it to generate a compiled c++ class, or other compiled object, that can be interfaced with c++?

The final result doesn't need to be human readable, and it can be system specific. I want to be able to do this at compile time. It does not have to happen at run time. I will know at run time what classes I need. It's just that the classes I will be making (and there will be a lot of them) are all very similar, and just deviate in a few key places. So I want a way to tell the computer the important stuff (which may only take 5 or 6 lines of code), and have it generate the other 30 lines of boiler plate code.

I'm making a game engine, and I am trying to design a system that allows me to plug and play with systems, without having to write a lot of boiler plate code.

Someone commented that I should make the example simpler. So here goes.

I'm trying to build a system that takes a text file input and builds me a compiled c++ binary. It doesn't have to be a text file, and it doesn't have to be specifically c++, as long as it can interface with c++ (relatively easily). This is to decrease the amount of boiler plate code, and number of short kinda useless c++ files that are all almost identical.

For example having a file called example.txt which looks like this.

```
objectGenerator ExampleClass {
autofunction[hello world]
}
```

I would then hope to generate something that functions similarly to a c++ class like

```cpp
class ExampleClass
{
public:
    void callAutoFunctions()
    {
        helloWorld();
    }

private:
    AutoFunction helloWorld;
};
```

then in my main.cpp for example I could call

```
void main()
{
    GeneratedClasses::ExampleClass exampleClass; 
    exampleClass.callAutoFunctions();
}
```

to print "hello world".

I want to be able to do this so I can make lots of different game objects that I can pull parts out of easily (by just changing one or two lines of text). It would make iterating over game ideas much easier, and in the long run would mean my games aren't the tangled mess of references and convoluted solutions to easy problems that they normally are.

I don't mind If I have to write a script in a different language than c++. It will make my indie game design career a lot easier if I could set this up now, and just use it for all my games in the future.

p.s. I'm trying to remake a [game](https://youtu.be/8CV7MTSfCQk) I created in python arcade over a year ago, but in c++ so it runs better, and I can actually create an exe file for the game that I can give to friends, or add to itch.io. I know that it is very bold of me to assume I will be able to make a viable, sellable game when I've coded in c++ for less than a year, but I am a task driven person and I wouldn't have the motivation to learn the c++ I need without doing something over the top like this.

Comment: C++ has templates.

Comment: you can use a script to automate code generation, compilation and liking. What is your question?

Comment: I'm aware of templates, but from the little I know I couldn't make it adjustable. I don't know how many properties an entity will have. 

@Serge that is exactly what I would like to know. How to automatically generate code. I didn't even think of searching that up so thank you.

Comment: *"Is there a way to take a text file and automatically generate c++ code?"* No. It's not like some high level languages. You can generate *.cpp file, but that file has to be compiled in to binary executable for a specific system. I think you should make a simplified version of this game, closer to "hello world" program, and post it.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. It takes about 3-5 years of study, guided by multiple C++ textbooks, before one gets average knowledge and understanding of C++ fundamentals: classes, methods, inheritance, multiple inheritance, polymorphism, overloading, containers, algorithms, multithreading, templates, parameter packs, type traits, and many more. And only after having a solid grasp of the basics can then one proceed into studying boutique areas, such as writing a "game engine". Without a solid grasp on the basics, this always end in tears.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. Oh I totally understand. I'm currently reading through multiple c++ programming books, and I can see it's complexity. The issue is I'd rather struggle and fight to program some crappy game engine while learning all I can than write contrived pointless programs. c++ isn't my first programming language, and from what little I have already worked with I can see it's far more intricate and powerful. I don't care that its going to end it tears, because at least it's going to end.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani. I don't want it in c++ code format. It doesn't have to be human readable. The text files can be converted to binary if that needs to happen. If I can't do that how I'm asking that's fine. the program could convert it straight into machine code, as long as it can communicate with the rest of my code I'm happy.

Comment: Just a recommendation, don't create your own DSL. Rather, create like a JSON schema that can be easily interpreted and then spit out the generated c++ code. Something like `{"class":{"identifier":"ExampleClass","memberFunctions":[{"access_specifier":"public","identifier":"callAutoFunctions","body":"helloWorld();"}]}}`

Comment: @BradyDean thank you. I don't mind using json as I have used it before (I just wanted to make my own as a learning tool, and because I find json overly verbose for what I need). Your message implies I can use a schema (or something of the like) to generate c++ code. Do you have any good sources of any suggested places I look?

Comment: @Barmak Shermirani. I have already begun designing a render engine using Vulkan, and I'm using glfw for the user input. That part is covered already. I'm hoping that after this game I will have to knowledge to make a competent 3D game. I'm just doing a 2D game to make the math and stuff simpler.

Comment: Have you considered using Lua scripts (https://www.lua.org/)? Lua was designed to be easily embedded in other languages.

Comment: C++ simply does not work this way. All classes in a C++ program are declared and defined at compile time. Classes are not something that can be created, ad-hoc, at runtime. "builds me a compiled c++ binary" -- this is what a C++ compiler does. I suppose that one could write some code that writes out a C++ source file, then runs the C++ compiler to compile it into an executable. But I doubt that this kind of a house of cards will stay up for long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like all you want is separate compilation. Firstly, you make an interface for the part of your game you wish to make more decoupled:

```
// Player.hpp

#include <memory>

struct IPlayer {
  virtual void run() = 0;
  virtual ~IPlayer() = default;
};

std::unique_ptr<IPlayer> getPlayer();
```

Then use it in your program without supplying the implementation:

```
// main.cpp

#include "Player.hpp"

int main() {
  auto player = getPlayer();
  player->run();
}
```

Then you compile it without linking:

```
$ clang++ -c main.cpp -O3 -Wall -Wextra
```

Now you work on your actual implementations:

```
// FastPlayer.cpp

#include "Player.hpp"

struct FastPlayer : IPlayer {
  void run() override { /* ... */ }
}

std::unique_ptr<IPlayer> getPlayer() {
  return std::unique_ptr<IPlayer>{ new FastPlayer };
}
```

Then compile whichever implementation you wish to test now and link it with the binary you compiled previously:

```
$ clang++ FastPlayer.cpp main.o -O3 -Wall -Wextra
```

This way you can swap out the implementations easily to test a lot of functionality. It is safer than loading arbitrary code at run time.

Ideally, you wouldn't do this manually and would have a build system like CMake handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add new classes to your application after it is built (compiled and linked in to exe file).

Technically you can use C to write your own language, that's how they made Python or Java. Just use those to start with if that's the right tool. It'll take 400 years to write something like that on your own.

External binaries can be used. You have to link to them during build time. Libraries usually use the C interface, it's easy to find a function by unique name and call it. To use the c++ libraries, both your application and library have to be built by the same c++ compiler, same compiler version and setting. This is useful, for example, to access standard libraries.

Normally you want to avoid writing libraries for your own application. Just write as many classes as you want in single executable, run it with different parameters.

You can write classes for game, player, ball, etc. Save the previous state in file and read it again. `cgame` can have its own `cplayer`, `cball` etc. This will fit every situation.

C++ doesn't have functionalities like Javascript which can recognize `onclick()` as a command. You have to save the string `"onclick"` in a file, read it, parse it, and interpret it yourself.

The closest thing is saving plain data structure:

```
struct plain_data
{
    int speed;
    int size;
    int previous;
    //don't put classes and pointers here
};

plain_data data = { 1,2,3 };
std::ofstream fout("file.dat", std::ios::binary);
fout.write((char*)&data, sizeof(data));
fout.close();

std::ifstream fin("file.dat", std::ios::binary);
fin.read((char*)&data, sizeof(data));
fin.close();
```

---

Edit

Lets say you want make a c++ game like Halo, or Doom Eternal. This can be done without a scripting language. You just need external libraries for handling images etc.

Now lets say you want to make a program which can play any game. At the time when this program is developed, you don't know anything about that game, it could be ping pong, or it could be a card game or something else. This will need a scripting language.

The latter is a more complicated task. It shouldn't be your first attempt in c++ development. You might consider Java-like languages with "Just in time compiler" which take text commands and turn them in to binaries in run time.

Comment: Writing your own scripting language or DSL definitely does not "take 400 years", it's something that can easily be done in less than a week (JavaScript was created in 10 days). Creating tools for such a language is a different question (and also whether a custom language is the right solution)

Comment: @UnholySheep That was the original Javascript with a few functions, it didn't have classes. To write a scripting language with the efficiency of Java or Python, and their functionality, I think 400 years. It's opinion based, I don't really know.

Comment: Thank you! I think what I'm looking for is external binaries as you said. I'm well aware I couldn't do this at run time, but I don't want to. what I'm taking away from this is that I will have to write my own (Very Simple) DSL which I interpret into an external binary which I link to my program at compile time. 

The reason I even want to do this is so anything in my game is generic. Technically if I wanted I could put the player movement script on a random tree by simply changing one line in an another file, and compiling it.

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe it becomes more clear.